# Automatically turn a string into a formatted string? (Python)

Tags: python, printf, f-string, self-healing

I'd like to program an alternate print() function, that automatically turns the inputted string into a formatted one, with correct formatting for variables.

So why doesn't this work?

```
Test = 'Hello!'

def prints(druck):
    for el in druck.split():
        print(f'{el}')

prints('Hello? Test')
```

The output is:

```
Hello?
Test
```

I want the output to be:

```
Hello?
Hello!
```

At the moment I only put one word into prints(). In the end I want to be able to print variables inside of longer strings without having to {} them.

My dream would be to have a print() function that would check if a word is a variable (something like if el == {el}?) and prints it out correctly, no matter the format.

This is my first question here :) Sorry for any inconveniences! And thanks.

Comment: Why did you pass `'Test'` instead of `Test`? Was that a mistake, or do you actually want your `prints` function to take a 4-character string with characters `T`, `e`, `s`, and `t`, and somehow get `'Hello!'` out of that?

Comment: Thank you for your question! Maybe I oversimplified the example. In the end I want to write 
prints('jau Test')
and get 'jau Hallo!' out of it. I want the string 'Test' to be turned into the variable Test.
I will change the question to make it more comprehensible.

Comment: @Emse technically it is possible by reading the locals and globals and checking if the variables are there but why specifically do you want this? Having this instead of the normal `print` sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. Why for example do f-strings not meet your usecase?

Comment: "My dream would be to have a print() function that would check if a word is a variable (something like if el == {el}?) and prints it out correctly, no matter the format." - that kind of autodetection is a bad idea. There's a reason Python doesn't automatically do this already. You end up with all sorts of nasty problems when you want to *actually print* a word that you happened to also be using as a variable name, which is **extremely** common.

Comment: Also for example can't you just write `print("Hello?", Test, sep="\n")` for the usecase you mentioned in the question? `print` can take a variable number of arguments if you are not aware.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Oh, basically I just wanted to make typing easier… Didn't know that would cause so many problems, since I am a beginner in this. Why type f'Hello? {Test}' when I could type 'Hello? Test' and get the same result?
I'm a little obsessed with the idea of letting the program take the work of programming. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Emse from the Zen of Python: "_Explicit is better than implicit._" Implicitly converting part of the string to the value of a variable is quite likely to cause issues, if someone needs to use the value of the `Test` variable it is best to be explicit about wanting to use it.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I realize that my idea would be stupid for any use case. But actually I wanted to unterstand the principle of it (Why isn't the second output 'Hello' or even f'Test'?
Also I think this principle could develop into code that automatically corrects its own typing errors, couldn't it?

Comment: Your code *explicitely* says to print the content of the `el` variable, and `el` is the string `'Hello?'` the first time, and the string `'Test'` the second time. You see, everything is simple when it's explicit! ;)

Comment: F-strings have to be defined in code. That is an important security feature since they can contain code.

Comment: Protip: don't get obsessed with meta programming. Learn to program the way the textbook teaches it. That's already plenty simple in Python, you don't need any helpers to make it even easier. Yes, programming involves typing, you better get used to that. You reduce the amount of typing by writing efficient, lean code; and by using an IDE that helps you with autocompletions. Of course, to be able to write lean code you'll first be writing a ton of crap code before you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `globals()`.

```py
def prints(druck):
    for el in druck.split():
        print(globals().get(el, el))
```

But you should still probably just use normal f-strings for reasons already mentioned in the comments.

Sorry if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Oh but it does! Thank you dimani128 and deceze. As I haven't got 15 reputation yet I cant't upvote anything, I'm sorry.
And Thierry, sorry, if I messed up my first question so bad that it wasn't understandable… even got downvoted… Thank you for your time and brains.

Answer (score -1):

You are facing this problem because you didn't use the variable as the argument instead you passed a string.

In simple words, variables are used without quotes.

This will solve the problem `prints('Hello? ' + Test)`

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for your answer!
But actually I wanted to know, why my function isn't working. As I see it, it should take each of the words of the string 'Hello?' and 'Test?' and print it as a formatted string f'{Hello?}' and f'{Test}'. But it didn't print f'{Test}', did it? Because if it did, the output should be "Hello!" instead of "Test".

Answer (score -3):

Hey there – Suprisingly I've come up with a solution myself which meets my needs!

```
def prints(druck):
for el in druck.split():
    try:
        print(eval(el), end=" ")
    except:
        print(el, end=" ")
```

Now I can just type in whatever I want and python will try to run each word of it as code before displaying.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please don't do that. Don't use eval. Just try `it = 3; from math import sin; prints('it is a sin to use eval, exit and more will bite you')` and see the output: `3 is a <built-in function sin> to use (<built-in function eval>,) <IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall object at 0x7fb9d4429850> and more will bite you `. And that could be much worse.

Comment: Tihi… All I can promise is not to use it while programming missile launch sequences ;)
I'll be careful!